# Почему можно не писать include, если в качестве поля указатель на объект

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, типы-данных

Почему можно не писать include "SomeClase.h", а достаточно просто написать class SomeClass; если в качестве поля указатель на объект?

```
class SomeClass;

class ClassOne {

...

SomeClass *someObject;
}
```

Comment: Скорее наоборот, вы можете объявить поле данного типа, если имеете прототип ```class SomeClass;```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неверно сформулировали вопрос. Давайте переформулируем его иначе - почему достаточно указать неполное объявление класса

```
class SomeClass;
```

если он используется только в качестве ссылки или указателя?

Потому что размер указателя/ссылки известен заранее, а больше в этот момент компилятору ничего знать и не надо - никакое внутреннее содержимое этого класса, так что ему достаточно неполного типа.

Вот если вы начнете использовать его внутреннее содержимое - например, вызов `someObject->func()` или даже если просто нужен полный его размер - тогда без полного типа не обойтись...

Это, конечно, не строгое и не полное пояснение, но примерно, чтоб понимать...

Comment: Т.е. мы используем class SomeClass, чтобы не подключать текст класса через include, чтобы не нагружать компилятор при парсинге хедера?

Comment: Нет, такое делается обычно для разрыва циклических связей - класс A использует класс B, который использует класс A :)